# Maintaining bitcoins

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core

instead of maintaining digital wallet and syncing the blockchain, is it okay if I just use paper wallet now and later import the addresses in digital wallet?
Will I get all my transactions to show up in digital wallet?

Answer (score 3):

Yes that would work. In fact, depending on the wallet, you can even import the address (the *public* part) and see the transactions. Only when you want to *send* bitcoins would you need to import the private key.

Comment: A Note: if you use the "watch only" feature on a blockchain.info wallet the mobile app may return errors if you try to pay from "any address" since it can't access the coins in the watch-only address for spending. The simple solution is to pick an address with available coins for sending, or use the web-based interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work fine.  When you import a key from a paper wallet, the computer wallet should scan the transaction history and pick up all previous transactions involving the newly added address.